# Block additional document contents after appendices

Tags: sectioning, appendices, etoolbox, documentclass-writing, preamble

I'm using the `appendix` package's `appendices` environment, and due to style changes for the appendices, placing anything after the appendices doesn't make sense. I'd like to raise an error if anything is placed after the `appendices` environment (or block otherwise). Maybe by doing something in `etoolbox`'s `\AfterEndEnvironment{appendices}{...}`?

I could redefine `\section` to give an error, but was wondering if there's anything more all-encompassing. A comment mentions emulating how content in the preamble raises an error, how would that be done?

Comment: You can copy what LaTeX does to flag text typeset before `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Have references with examples for how to do so?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what style changes persist after `\end{appendices}`? I thought localized changes were the point of having an environment instead of the standard LaTeX `\appendix` command.

Comment: I should use the `\appendix` command instead, now that I think about it. I loaded the `appendix` package to do some ToC stuff, and saw that it had an `appendices` environment and thought "why not?". Just need to make sure everything works as before. Specifically, the page numbering is changed to be prepended with "A".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LaTeX uses an internal macro `\@nodocument` to raise an error if typesetting occurs before `\begin{document}`. It is included in some other macros, and in `\everypar`, but at the begin-document it is removed from `\everypar` and redefined to do nothing. You want to reverse that with the end of appendices.

```
% in a .sty or after \makeatletter
% LaTeX defines:
%\gdef\@nodocument{%
%  \@latex@error{Missing \protect\begin{document}}\@ehd}
% similarly:
\gdef\@afterappendix{%
    \@latex@error{Text found after the appendices}\@ehd}
\g@addto@macro\endappendices{\global\let\@nodocument\@afterappendix
    \global\everypar{\@afterappendix}}
% or use \AfterEndEnvironment
```

It appears the `\end{appendices}` does not end a paragraph in progress, so that can be patched along with adding the error message. The error help text can be more specific, but the generic `\@ehd` is not bad. Forcibly ending the document can be done after the error message, and would need a more specific error help text.

Using these additions, and assuming this is defined by document class xxxxxx

```
\gdef\@afterappendix{%
  \global\let\@afterappendix\relax
  \ClassError{xxxxxx}{Text found after the appendices}%
      {Placing anything after the appendices doesn't make sense,\MessageBreak
       so the document will be forcibly ended here.}\enddocument}
\g@addto@macro\endappendices{\par
    \global\let\@nodocument\@afterappendix
    \global\everypar{\@afterappendix}}
```

Comment: Is `\@ehd` needed if `\ClassError` is used instead? Just a note, the error won't appear if text is placed immediately after the `appendices` environment. This can be fixed with `\AtEndEnvironment{appendices}{\clearpage}`.

Comment: An alternative method I found was `\AfterEndEnvironment{appendices}{\enddocument}`. However, this just gobbles everything rather than giving an error, and makes the ending `\end{document}` redundant.

Comment: Yes, you could and probably should use a more helpful error-help text than `\@ehd`. If `\end{appendices}` can leave you in the middle of a paragraph, that sounds like a bug in appendices. That can be patched along with the error message insertion.